# "nach unwiederbringlich Verlorenem"

Tags: adjective, adverb, nominalization

Wenn man einem substantivierten Adjektiv ein Attribut voranstellen möchte, gilt dieses Attribut als Adverb oder Adjektiv? Bleibt es dementsprechend zwangsläufig unflektiert? Ich nenne ein Beispiel aus Hesses "Steppenwolf":

> So von Gedanken und vom Nachklang der Musik erfüllt, das Herz schwer von Trauer und verzweifelter Sehnsucht nach Leben, nach Wirklichkeit, nach Sinn, **nach unwiederbringlich Verlorenem**, (...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das hängt von der Bedeutung ab.

> 1) ein stark Schwitzender ~ eine Person, die stark schwitzt
>
> 2) ein starker Schwitzender ~ eine starke Person, die schwitzt

Die Umschreibungen geben den Bedeutungsunterschied recht gut wieder. Das unflektierte Adjektiv ist adverbial, in der Paraphrase modifiziert es das Verb, also den Vorgang; das flektierte dagegen schreibt der bezeichneten Person oder Sache eine Eigenschaft zu.

Comment: Die derzeitige Hitzewelle hinterlässt Ihre Spuren :-P ...